# GWT checking if textbox is empty

Tags: gwt, textbox

Im working on a school project and i'm trying to check in GWT if a textbox i create is empty or not. I have done the exact same thing on another project and there it worked fine. i have searched for the answer here and on google but couldn't find any answer.

```
voornaamTB = new TextBox();
voornaamTB.setText(null);

ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (voornaamTB != null) {
                System.out.println("not empty");
            } else {
                System.out.println("empty");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
if(!voornaamTB.getText().isEmpty()) { ...
```

will work. You're currently testing to see whether the TextBox itself is null, which it isn't as you initialized it on the first line.

You probably don't need the setText(null) after immediately creating it.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting and accepting this answer? Thanks. :)

Comment: You can also check `getText().isEmpty()` which is slightly shorter (you don't have to worry about the case of an empty string)

Answer (score 1):

Your object is not empty, so you can get only not empty. try this

```
voornaamTB = new TextBox();
voornaamTB.setText(null);

ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (voornaamTB.getText() != null) {
                System.out.println("not empty");
            } else {
                System.out.println("empty");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The text will (I believe) never be null. It will always be some string with some length. If the length == 0, or empty, then you have an empty textbox.

Comment: I found @JasonHall 's comment to anecdotally be correct [anecdotally in my own project].