# GWT Regex and empty string

Tags: regex, gwt, string

Could someone explain why this snip :

```
// import com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.MatchResult;
// import com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp;

RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("^$");
MatchResult matcher;
while ((matcher = regExp.exec("")) != null)
{
    System.out.println("match " + matcher);
}
```

give an incredible count of matches? I tested with different modifier allowed by GWT implementation of *compile()*, g, i and m. It works only with m (multiline).
I just want to check for empty string.

[EDIT] the new method

```
private ArrayList<MatchResult> getMatches(String input, String pattern)
{
    ArrayList<MatchResult> matches = new ArrayList<MatchResult>();
    if(null == regExp)
    {
        regExp = RegExp.compile(pattern, "g");
    }
    if(input.isEmpty())
    {
        // empty string : just check if pattern validate and
        // don't try to extract matches : it will resutl in infinite
        // loop.
        if(regExp.test(input))
        {
            matches.add(new MatchResult(0, "", new ArrayList<String>(0)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(input); matcher != null; matcher = regExp
                .exec(input))
        {
            matches.add(matcher);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: I guess because ^$ looks for start of a line and then end of a line which is why multiline works. I don't know why you didn't think of just using .isEmpty() ?

Comment: Its because this code comes from a generic class that already process a lot of regex, and that one (detect empty string) is a bit problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `regExp.exec("")` with `RegExp.compile("^$")` will never return `null`, as the empty string `""` is a match for regex `^$`, which reads *"nothing between beginning and the end of line/string"*.

So your `while` is infinity loop.

Also, you print is

```
System.out.println("match " + matcher);
```

...but you probably wanted to use

```
System.out.println("match " + matcher.getGroup(0));
```

---

Also see [GWT checking if textbox is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264288/gwt-checking-if-textbox-is-empty).

Comment: Also, even with the _global_ flag, `getLastIndex` would always be 0 (as there's no other index in the string), which is why it never returns null either. BTW, `com.google.gwt.rexexp` is a simple, lightweight, wrapper around JS `RegExp`s, so it should behave the same.